# Error: 0xC002918F at FTP Task, FTP Task: Unable to connect to FTP server using "FTP Connection Manager"

Tags: ftp, sftp, connection, ssis, winscp

I am trying to download data files from a FTP server to local machine through SSIS. But it throws the error

> Error: 0xC002918F at FTP Task, FTP Task: Unable to connect to FTP server using "FTP Connection Manager".

I have even explored all the articles regarding it and even changed the protection level to all the types, but none seems to be working. Please do help me. Attached screenshots shall help you.

[Connection manager settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djEL1.png)

[Error while connecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hX9Mu.png)

[FTP task settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDqgY.png)

[WinSCP Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7e11E.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting using SFTP protocol in WinSCP.

FTP and SFTP are two completely different protocols. You cannot expect that you can use an FTP client (SSIS FTP Task) and it will connect to SFTP server, if you change a port to 22. It won't.

SSIS does not support SFTP. You have to use a 3rd party solution. WinSCP can be used to implement SFTP in SSIS:

- either [using its scripting interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ssis):
- or [using WinSCP .NET assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_ssis).

Comment: Thank you for your support in making me understand about connecting to SFTP server through FTP client.  Tried your method and every possible way. But couldn't perhaps its our firewall issue. Finally implemented .net script code shared by my colleagues.